# converting .py into HTML

Tags: python, html

I have a python file test.py

```
import os
print os.system("dir")

def test():
    a = 5 + 6
    print a
test()
```

I want to convert this test.py into HTML file so that I can view the file in HTML browser with same indentation and formats.

Is there any way or module which converts my python file into HTML and vice versa?

Comment: do not downvote. I asked because I have no idea.

Comment: @Havenard : can you please guide me in detail about that tag?

Comment: There are several code conversion utilities available. Google is your best friend. I use `Highlight` on Windows which is a code highlighter. It can output results in rtf, html, latex, and a host of other formats, using different themes. It can also add line numbers etc. Give it a try.

Comment: http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
<pre>
import os
print os.system("dir")

def test():
    a = 5 + 6
    print a
test()
</pre>
```

`pre` tag displays text with fixed-width font, and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Comment: but when I open this file in IDLE or Eclipse, I get import, print etc functions in different colors which I am not able to see in HTML. I can see all black lines. Can I maintain that colors as well? Is there any script which preserves the same and converts .py to HTML?

Comment: When you convert the file into .html, the computer sees the file as a HTML file and therefore it cannot do Python's syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but you can use Jupyter Notebook.
Paste your code in a cell and export the notebook as HTML.